# How is the orchestration function suspended in Azure Durable Functions

Tags: async-await, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I believe I conteptually understand what's goind on in Azure Durable Functions. You have to start an Orchestration Function where you can await Activities. When an activity is completed, the Orchestration Function starts from the top, but since the activity now has a result, the result is used instead of invoking it again.

This means the Orchestration Functions 'goes to sleep'. I've been looking into the source of both the Azure Durable Functions and Durable Task Framework on GitHub, but I can't quite find the actual lines of code that impact the callback of the awaited tasks.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on the topic (have been looking into how durable task myself lately) but essentially, the 'sleep' is achieved by scheduling tasks. All durable tasks (orchestrator and activities) are triggered by queue messages and in case of orchestrations, are replayed each time.

Coming to the code, most of this done in the [Durable Task framework](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask) itself. And for your specific query

1. Orchestrator Execution runs [here](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/cba0ba4db8cd46288323fdaecf510e0a61ed5df8/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationDispatcher.cs#L221), returning any pending orchestration actions
2. Schedule next steps (activity, timers, etc.) [here](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/cba0ba4db8cd46288323fdaecf510e0a61ed5df8/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationDispatcher.cs#L365). The implementation for `CompleteTaskOrchestrationWorkItemSync` is in on the providers and for Durable Functions, its [Azure Storage Queues](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/master/src/DurableTask.AzureStorage/AzureStorageOrchestrationService.cs#L836).

There is no real sleep, but once the orchestration action is completed, another message with the response would trigger the orchestration function, causing it to replay.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer this question myself, I suspected that the continuation scheduling after `await` is being customised. As I understand it, that would require an implementation of [`System.Threading.SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext), so I looked for that in the Durable Task Framework and found [`TaskOrchestrationSynchronizationContext`](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/f79aab253643e815348ae232bb9a7009c34e70ab/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationExecutor.cs#L237), and it is being set as the current context in [`ExecuteCore`](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask/blob/f79aab253643e815348ae232bb9a7009c34e70ab/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationExecutor.cs#L99). And if you look further down you can see the previous context is restored.

I suspect that during the time that this custom context is current (e.g. in `ExecuteCore`), `IDurableOrchestrationContext.CallActivityWithRetryAsync<T>()` is `await`ed, and that the return value (e.g. `Task.Result`) is stored (in the task hub table in Azure Storage), and, rather then scheduling the continuation on a thread from the thread pool, **the continuation is discarded**, and activity finished is signaled (with a message on one of the Azure Storage queues).

At this point **your code** is not being executed. If you are debugging the application locally, then the application is running. But if you are running the application on Azure, then the application could be stopped.

Of course, the message on the Azure Storage queue will trigger the orchestration pretty soon afterwards though, and the function will start 'from the top'.

Disclaimer: my answer is based on how `await` works, but I did not actually take the time to verify this beyond finding the custom `SynchronizationContext` and extrapolating from there.